# Edit authentication page with django

Tags: django

I am quite new to django, and am trying to create a simple and standard log in set up.

I will be using django-registraion (begrudgingly tho, because the author doesnt know how to clearly document his efforts...)

Anyway, i was wondering how to go about setting up a simple "edit your profile" page. In a similar question i asked before, i was directed to read the django tutorial (not useful) and told that th auth component offered this functionality (but not where the doco was for it) - anybody have any clear steps to do this?

Cheers.

Comment: django-registration is created by James Bennet who is one of the people responsible for django's renowned overall documentation so I think the problem might fall with your ability to consume the information considering that it's one of the most throughly documented projects out there. Next time you have a problem, don't lace your question with attitude and insult one of Django's main contributors

Comment: I understand you are quite new to django, but remember no pain no gain ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do it from scratch. Assuming you have a UserProfile model one way to go about doing this is to use django forms. For example if you have

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60 , blank=True, null=True )
    gender = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=SEX_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)

    bio  = models.TextField()
```

you will then need to implement a userprofile form if you want(makes your life easy) Like so :

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user') #you dont want anybody seeing this :)
```

ModelForm because in the event a user has the abillity to change any details it would reflect in database.

Next you would write a view function for updating the profile: here is to getting you started

```
def edit_profile(request):
    view_kwargs = {
        'model': UserProfile, 
        'form_class': UserProfileForm,
        'success_url': "/path/to/success",
        ),
        'template_name': "/path/to/edit_profile.html",
    }

    user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user_id=request.user)


     #TODO
```

if all else fails you can always use django-profiles which is a standalone application

Comment: sorry for the lengthy answer.